# Drools 6.4.0 fails with error uncomparable values

Tags: java, java-8, drools

I have java class Fact as below

```
class AssertionFact {
   String name;
   Object value;
}
```

When i was using Drools 5.2 & rule as below it was working perfectly fine.

```
AssertionFact(
                                    object > 100,
                                    name == "testName"
                                )
```

But now when i have upgraded my drools version to 6.4.0 & JDK 1.8 I am getting below error for same rules.

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: uncomparable values <<TESTVALUE>> and <<100.0>>
    at org.mvel2.math.MathProcessor.doOperationNonNumeric(MathProcessor.java:274)
    at org.mvel2.math.MathProcessor._doOperations(MathProcessor.java:234)
    at org.mvel2.math.MathProcessor.doOperations(MathProcessor.java:79)
    at org.mvel2.ast.BinaryOperation.getReducedValueAccelerated(BinaryOperation.java:117)
    at org.mvel2.MVELRuntime.execute(MVELRuntime.java:85)
    at org.mvel2.compiler.CompiledExpression.getDirectValue(CompiledExpression.java:123)
    at org.mvel2.compiler.CompiledExpression.getValue(CompiledExpression.java:119)
    at org.mvel2.MVEL.executeExpression(MVEL.java:929)
    at org.drools.core.util.MVELSafeHelper$RawMVELEvaluator.executeExpression(MVELSafeHelper.java:496)
```

Comment: Comparing an Object to a Number or String? Apparently Drools does a better job at checking now. -- Also, note that the DRL pattern does not agree with the class snippet where we hae `Object value` but the constraint refers to `object`.

Comment: My class definition i wrote is actullay wrong, it have object as property with Object class as it can hold string, Integer or Double. This same Rule definition is working fine in 5.2.0 but not in 6.4 or 6.3. I have many of such rules already written & cant modify them manually not.